# Update CSS Text Animation Time Duation for Every 5 Seconds

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have created a jumping text animation by using CSS. It's working good, but I want to updated some timing changes in that animation. Currently the animation occurs every seconds with infinite duration. But i want to update this animation for every **5 seconds** with infinite duration.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5rsvp915/)

```css
div.dancingtext {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal;
  animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='dancingtext'>Dancing Text!</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in function for delay in looped animations. But you can achieve this effect using a slight offset to all key-frames i.e.

```css
div.dancingtext {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  animation: jump 6.5s ease 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  3% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  9% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  12%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='dancingtext'>Dancing Text!</div>
```

Key-frames are very flexible to work with animations in CSS you can use any value combinations you like to achieve desired effect. I hope you get the idea.

> Note: Please add these CSS browser prefixes to make sure it works
>   across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You try the following code. Used jQuery.

```js
setInterval(function(){
 $("#animated-text").addClass("dancingtext");
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("#animated-text").removeClass("dancingtext");
  }, 1500);
}, 5000);
```

```css
div.text{
           font-size:30px;
         <!-- font-weight:bold; -->
         width:auto;
       margin:30px auto;
         text-align:center;
}
div.dancingtext {     
         -webkit-animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal ;
         animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal ;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes jump {
         0%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         20%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         40%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
         transform: translateY(-30px);
         }
         50%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         60%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
         transform: translateY(-15px);
         }
         80%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         100%{
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         }
         @keyframes jump {
         0%{
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         20%{
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         40%{
         transform: translateY(-30px);
         }
         50%{
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         60%{
         transform: translateY(-15px);
         }
         80%{
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         100%{
         transform: translateY(0);
         }
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animated-text" class='text'>Dancing Text!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Zico.. its also works.. but if it is in css then it will better for me.. anyway thanks again for the code.

Comment: @DineshKumar you should have mention that in your question!

Comment: im new to to stackoverflow.. i need 15 reputation to give up vote.. thats y up-voting pending.. im waiting some reply.. if this post doesnt get any reply i will mark your code to acceptable answer..